# VPS CentOS partition full, but my data is half of the space

Tags: centos, disk-space-utilization

I have a partition (EXT3 Journaled) mounted in /var/www/html/fcls with size

`df -h` gives

> /dev/sdc1             197G  195G     0 100% /var/www/html/fcls

I wrote about 100GB of files (many many files) and partition is full

I can see free inodes with `df -i`

> /dev/sdc1            26214400  570576 25643824    3% /var/www/html/fcls

Then I run `du -h --max-depth=1`

> 16K    ./lost+found
>
> 62M    ./ml3_debug
>
> 350M   ./ols5_debug
>
> 100G   ./ols5_dr
>
> 100G   .

Cannot understand why is full? (I have to mention that I am not sys admin, just a dev with some linux knowledge)

Comment: Try running this from `/`. It will find files over 50MB in size (my guess is it's a log file) `find . -type f -size +50000k -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'`

Comment: Result is 3 files: 129MB, 26GB and last one of 1.4GB

Comment: The 26GB is a log file and I can delete it

Comment: lsof -ns |grep deleted -> shows plenty big files ... should be the case?

Comment: WHat you may be seeing is processes that are running still have the files open. If a process has a file open (active file descriptor) then the space in that file cannot be reclaimed until the process closes the file, or terminates. Doing "rm" removes the directory entry, but the file is still there until it is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lsof -ns |grep deleted
```

Started to kill those processes and space appears :)